# Deleting user security loophole in linux

Tags: linux

I'm fairly new to linux and I have studied that one user can create and delete user. Suppose I logged in as root user and created two users A and B, now my question is that can user A delete user B and his home directory or vice versa using sudo deluser. If this is possible, shouldn't we consider it as a big blunder in linux.
If this is not the case, suppose I log in user A and grant myself all permission on home directory of B and then delete user B or its files.
Please tell me if this is possible. If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

By default users can't access `sudo`. To use it they must be added to `/etc/sudoers` configuration file or to a group which is allowed access to `sudo` in that file. This group is usually called `sudo` or `wheel`.

Without access to `sudo`, they can't run `sudo deluser` or take ownership of files they don't own.

You can safely try it yourself in a virtual machine.

Comment: If one user, say A, creates another user B(does user A need access to sudo to create B?), will user B be added to sudoers?? If not, how to add B to sudoers. And if B is a sudoer, will he be able to delete A?? I am struggling to understand these concepts!

Comment: One more thing, If I am a sudoer, would I be able to chown some other user's file and then delete it later. If this happenes, I think it is a security loophole

Comment: Users with `sudo` access have root powers, ie. full access to everything in the system. If someone can run `sudo`, the answer to all questions is "yes". It's not a security loophole - you _need_ such power to administer a system, for example to kick out users who abuse it. `sudo` access must be granted with great care.

Comment: @VipulTyagi - In a standard configuration, _no_ user is _ever_ added automatically to sudoers. The only way a user gains access to `sudo` is if someone else with root powers explicitly grants those powers to the user.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman If this is the case, then can some sudo user remove root user??

Comment: So sudo is only thing you want?? Create users, delete users, gain access to other users files, isn't it bad??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: My question is just that what powers a user gets when he becomes a sudoer

Comment: I've already answered this question. `sudo` lets the user do everything the system is capable of.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to say, it seems a big loophole. Think of a situation where every user with sudo access can remove any other user or access its files

Comment: That is exactly the point of `sudo`. Think of a situation where a user is abusing the system and hundreds of other users can't use it efficiently, but administrators can't do anything about it. System administrator must have greater power than regular users. `sudo` is not a toy and should only be available for users who can be trusted to make good use of it.

Comment: By the way, if you have physical access to a computer, you can just remove the hard drive, connect it to another computer where you have root privileges and modify that hard drive to make yourself a root there too. It's not a security loophole, it's how computers work and it's taken into consideration in the design of UNIX security model. Limiting power of `sudo` doesn't make sense, it would only force you to use such workarounds in emergency situations.

Comment: `sudo` is not a loophole since its scope is known and accepted. You give `sudo` only to trusted people. You can also instead give access to some very specific commands that require root privs. If you don't trust the people who have root access on a system with your files, then don't put your files on it.

Comment: Thank you @gronostaj for clearing the point to me. Is there any good resource for studying these concepts in depth?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of anything right now